# Cauchy's differentiation formula for bounded operators

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, cauchy-integral-formula, bochner-spaces

Let $T$ be a bounded operator on a Banach space $X$. It's known that by the Dunford-Riesz functional calculus and the Cauchy formula we have that,

$$
f(T) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial U} \frac{f(\lambda)} {\lambda - T} \, d\lambda,
$$

where $f$ is an holomorphic function in some neighbourhood of the spectrum $\sigma(T)$ of $T$ and $U$ is an open set such that $\sigma(T) \subset U$ and $\partial U$ consists of a finite number of rectificable Jordan curves oriented in positive sense.

On the other hand from complex analysis we have Cauchy's differentiation formula that states that if $f$ is an holomorphic complex function,

$$
f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma} \frac{f(z)} {(z - a)^{n+1}} \, dz,
$$
where $\Gamma$ is a rectificable Jordan curve.

My question is the following, can we say that this inequality holds also for bounded operators? That is, is it true that,

$$
f^{(n)}(T) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial U} \frac{f(\lambda)} {(\lambda - T)^{n+1}} \, d\lambda.
$$

The way I see it is that it has to hold considering the function $f^{(n)}$ in the Dunford-Riesz functional calculus and then do some integration by parts. The problem is that as we are working with a Bochner integral, i don't know how to properly continue.

Any reference is welcome as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will follow the construction shown in the book [1], in particular we follow section *1.9 The Riemann-Stieltjes Integral* and we will use 2 results:

#### First result

###### Formula (1.20)

It follows that if $g$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $F$, then so is $F$ with respect to $g$ (and vice versa, by symmetry) and the following formula of integration by parts holds:

$$
\int_a^b g(t) d F(t)=g(b) F(b)-g(a) F(a)-\int_a^b F(t) d g(t).
$$

#### Second result

###### Proposition 1.9.11

Let $g:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $F:[a, b] \rightarrow X$. If $F$ is an antiderivative of a Bochner integrable function $f$ and if $g$ is continuous, then $\int_a^b g(s) d F(s)$ exists and equals the Bochner integral $\int_a^b g(s) f(s) d s$. If $F$ is continuous and $g$ is absolutely continuous, then $\int_a^b F(s) d g(s)$ equals the Bochner integral $\int_a^b F(s) g^{\prime}(s) d s$.

---

### Answer to the question

We will restrict to the case where $\partial U$ is a circunference that is $\partial U = \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \mid \lvert \lambda \rvert = r\}$ for some $r>1$. Therefore by the Dunford-Riesz Calculus we have that,

$$
f'(T) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{ri f'(r e^{it})}{r e^{it} - T} \, dt.
$$

Calling $F(t) = \frac{1}{r e^{it} - T}$ and $g(t) = f(r e^{it})$ we have that,

$$
f'(T) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-\pi}^\pi F(t) dg(t),
$$

where, if we apply integration both results mentioned above we have that,

$$
\begin{aligned}
f'(T) & = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-\pi}^\pi F(t) dg(t) = -\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-\pi}^\pi g(t) dF(t) \\ & = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{r i f(r e^{it})}{(r e^{it} - T)^2}\, dt  = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial U} \frac{f(\lambda)}{(\lambda - T)^2}\, d\lambda.
\end{aligned}
$$

In order to obtain the general formula we just have to keep doing this trick.

**References**

[1] Arendt, W., Batty, C., Hieber, M., & Neubrander, F. (2011). Vector-valued Laplace transforms and Cauchy problems. (Vol. 96) Birkhäuser/Springer Basel AG, Basel.